# Match content between parenthesis and get the url and change it to img tag using RegExp PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I need to match something from content get the url from it and completely change the matched item.
here is my content look like:

```
$content = "A quick brown fox {img:https://imageurl.com/fox.jpg} jumps over the lazy dog {img:https//:imageurl.com/dog.jpg}.";
```

I need it like this:

```
echo $content;


A quick brown fox <img src='https://imageurl.com/fox.jpg' style='width:100%' /> jumps over the lazy dog. <img src='https//:imageurl.com/dog.jpg' style='width:100%' />;
```

I can get the links using `preg_match_all("/\{img:(.*?)\}/", $text, $matches);`  but don't know how to replace it.

Thanks in advance;

Comment: Stack Overflow is *not* a code writing service. 
We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. 
You are expected to try to write the code yourself.
Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i have tried this 'preg_match_all("/\{img:(.*?)\}/", $text, $matches);' to get he url but do not know how to replace it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is the data cutting between {}.

Try this:

```
$result = preg_replace("#\{img:(.*)\}#U",'<img src=\'$1\' style=\'width:100%\' />',$content);
```